# Is there a way to have pandas build a dataframe out of a user selected excel sheet?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to write a pandas script that can read any excel sheet you enter input into it without having to play around in the code itself. i want the user to be able to just select the file they want to use from a tkinter window, and then have it create a data frame from there.

I have a working tkinter window and a working pandas script, i just need to find a good way to merge the 2

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function which seems to do exactly what you want: read an excel file into a dataframe.